# Convex shape in ellipsoid containment test

Tags: geometry, algorithms, collision-detection

Supposed you to want find out if an ellipsoid fully contains a convex shape. In the picture below I have drawn two situations. The left shape is overlapping
with the ellipsoid, and the right shape is fully contained in it.
[image]
Using an algorithm like the GJK Expanding Polytope algorith (see e.g. 'Collision Detection in Interactive 3D Environments'), we can get a penetration depth vector, $\vec{d}$. Using the support function of the shape ($S$), and the ellipsoid ($E$), we can find the extreme points of the shape along the penetration depth vector. If S is fully contained, then $S_{max} < E_{max}$ and $S_{min} > E_{min}$, as is seen in the right-hand of the picture (in red), and where $S_{max} = s_S(\vec{d})$, $S_{min} = s_S(-\vec{d})$, and analogously for shape $E$.

I have drawn a 2D example for simplicity, but I'm mostly interested in the 3D case. I can't find anything wrong with this approach, but it would be quite slow for my needs. Unfortunately, I don't know the formal name of this kind of problem and could thus not find any other solutions that might have a better performance. It would be nice if any alternative approaches would work for general convex-shaped containers.